# Изменение фразеологизма

Tags: фразеология

Можно ли написать "задом да наперёд" вместо "задом наперёд"? В целях выдерживания песенных строк

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, можно. Примеры такой фразы даже реально найти на просторах сети, хотя в источниках вроде "нацкорпуса" они не зафиксированы. Нет жёсткого табу на изменение фразеологизма. Тема, кстати, раскрыта в ряде исследовательских работ. Ознакомиться можете по запросам "изменение состава фразеологизма" и "фразеологическое новаторство". Так что уверенно меняйте фразу, если того требует поэтическая задача.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: После «конечно» не нужна запятая. Следует разделять частицу «конечно», которая пресекает сомнения, ясные из контекста, и вводное слово «конечно», которое предшествует чему-то известному для всех.

Answer (score 1):

> "задом да наперёд"

Такое можно. "Да" - всего лишь усилительная частица, да и вообще несколько сомнительно, что перед нами - именно фразеологизм (оба слова используются в своем основном, естественном значении).

А вообще в фразеологизмах не рекомендуется менять - без специальной на то цели - знаменательные слова, даже на синонимичные: "муха носу не подточит" (вместо "комар"), "Как есть дать" (вместо "пить"), "ни к деревне, ни к городу" (вместо "селу") - все это примеры ошибок, возможно сознательно допущенных автором.

(+) ======

Я не предполагал, что придется отстаивать в общем-то такую самоочевидную вещь, как недопустимость немотивированной замены слов в фразеологизмах, но коли уж тут фронда возникла...

=================
Первая группа речевых ошибок связана с усвоением формы фразеологизмов:

> 1. Лексическое видоизменение фразеологизма:
>
> -немотивированное введение дополнительного компонента:
>
> ```
> Не маленький – пора уж за свой ум браться;
> ```
>
> -немотивированный пропуск компонента фразеологизма:
>
> ```
> Хоть об стенку бейся – опущен компонент – головой;
> ```
>
> -немотивированная замена одного компонента другим:
>
> ```
> Всё возвращается на спирали своя; правильно – на круги своя;
> ```
>
> -смешение компонентов двух близких по значению или по форме
> фразеологизмов.
>
> ```
>  Так, очень распространённой ошибкой является замена членов близких по  
>  значению устойчивых сочетаний: Язык не поднимается говорить об этом
>  (в данном случае произошло смешение компонентов двух фразеологизмов:
>  рука не поднимается, язык не поворачивается).
> ```

====
https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/802-66_rechevye_oshibki__svyazannye_s_upotrebleniem_frazeologizmov.html
(Источник неавторитетный, но весьма добротный и содержательный)

Там еще много интересных ошибок разбирается, но в рамках темы интересно именно отношение к немотивированному лексическому видоизменению фразеологизма.

(++)  ======
Вынужден добавить еще одно уточнение. Sharon приводит пример использования этого сочетания как фразеологизма. С этим могу согласиться, может быть фразеологизмом, да. Но это ничего не меняет. Совсем не очевидно, что у автора что-то подобное.

Вот у Чуковского.
*А за ними кот -
Задом наперед.*
(Тараканище)
Тут-то не фразеологизм?!

*Художники по-разному понимают сказанное Чуковским: то сам котяра едет, то его медведи везут, то на велосипеде, то нет, но везде прослеживается наличие именно развернутого против движения кота.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это в общем-то малосущественно...
Меня совершенно не убеждает, что появление усилительной частицы "да" (ну не союз же это, в самом деле?) является вмешательством во внутреннюю структуру фразеологизма.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123430/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus--).

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно написать ***задом да наперед***, но это будет считаться **поэтической вольностью.** Допустимость замены может определить сам автор по тому, насколько гармонично измененный стих вписался в общий текст.

**Примечание.** Поэтическая вольность – это не редкость в стихосложении,  такое случается даже  в грамматике. Интересен случай со стихотворением Лермонтова: "*Не встретит ответа Средь шума мирского **Из пламя** и света Рожденное слово*". Существует предположение, что поэт хотел как-то исправить стих (***из пламени***), но потом решил оставить.

2. Обычно же авторы  используют изменение фразеологизма **в каких-то целях:** для усиления экспрессии, для сатирического эффекта и т.д., то есть это намеренное изменение, которое для всех очевидно. Например, об этом сказано в статье

2.1.8.3. Преобразование состава фразеологизма
[https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL04/70648414.html#id-21Понятиефразеологическойстилистики-219%C2%A0Речевыеошибкисвязанныесупотреблениемфразеологизмов](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL04/70648414.html#id-21%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-219%C2%A0%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2)

3. В общем же случае фразеологизм, как говорится, менять **можно, но очень осторожно**. Что-то допускается, а что-то категорически **под запретом.** К тому же надо учитывать, что **варианты изменения**  уже обозначены в словарях, например: ***Слыханное (слыхано) ли дело*** ( прост.) — о чем-л. совершенно необычном, невозможном, недопустимом.

**Свойства фразологизмов**

(1) **Большинству фразеологизмов свойственна** **непроницаемость структуры**: не допускается включение в них новых слов. Так, зная фразеологизм *потупить голову,* нельзя сказать: *низко потупить голову*. Однако есть и такие фразеологизмы, которые допускают вставку отдельных уточняющих слов (ср.: *разжигать страсти – разжигать роковые страсти, намылить голову – хорошенько намылить голову*).

(2)  **Фразеологизмам присуща устойчивость грамматического строения**, в них обычно не меняются грамматические формы слов. Так, нельзя сказать *бить баклушу*, заменив формы множественного числа *баклуши,* или употребить полное прилагательное вместо краткого во фразеологизме *на босу ногу*. Однако в особых случаях вариации грамматических форм во фразеологизмах возможны (*греть руку – греть руки, слыханное ли дело –  слыхано ли дело*).

**Большинство фразеологизмов имеет строго закрепленный порядок слов.** Например, нельзя поменять местами слова в выражениях *ни свет ни заря*; *битый небитого везет; все течет, все изменяется; ни рыба ни мясо*, хотя смысл, казалось бы, не пострадал, если бы мы сказали: «Все изменяется, все течет». В то же время в некоторых фразеологизмах возможно изменение порядка слов (ср.: *набрать в рот воды – в рот воды набрать, не оставить камня на камне – камня на камне не оставить*). Перестановка компонентов обычно допускается во фразеологизмах, состоящих из глагола и зависящих от него именных форм.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ  (по просьбе участника форума)**

**1. Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка.** —
М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008.

**ЗАДОМ НАПЕРЁД**

1. Разг. Шутл. В обратном порядке. Случается иногда и то, что там, где должно поставить конец, ставят начало, и таким образом часто публика имеет удовольствие видеть, что драмы выставляют перед нею задом наперёд (Крылов. Почта духов).
2. Не так, как следует; не так, как полагается. Петя присел на большой камень и перевёл дух… Что теперь делать? Всё вышло задом наперёд, и ничего уже не исправить (В. Катаев. Белеет парус одинокий).

**2.   Да – частица?**

Больше оснований считать, что  слово в данном случае является союзом, в словарной статье про частицу нет такого значения.

**ДА, союз.** 1. (соединяет однородные чл. предл., повторяющиеся сл. и предл.). =И. Хороший да пригожий. Старые да малые. Сидеть на воде да на хлебе. Работа "подними да брось". Хлеб да соль вам! Нужен глаз да глаз за кем-л. (усилит.). Осталась кожа да кости.

**3. Вы можете спросить меня, в чем же вольность?**

Я думаю, что вольность в данном случае состоит **в нарушении следующего правила:**  Большинству фразеологизмов свойственна непроницаемость структуры: не допускается включение в них новых слов. Изменение состава фразеологизма возможно с какой-то  стилистической целью, но таковой не является **"выдерживание песенных строк".**

Comment: *но это будет считаться поэтической вольностью* - А в чем вольность-то? Можете источник показать, где бы русским по белому говорилось, что добавление усилительной частицы было бы "вольностью"?! Не говоря уж о том, что само отнечение к фразеологизмам подобного сочетание весьма дискуссионно.

Comment: *Разг. Шутл. В обратном порядке.* - Аааа... Спасибо. Никогда не сталкивался с использованием в таком значении. Кажется надуманным. Но уж коли в словарь попало... Пример из Крылова неубедителен, здесь вполне проходит и прямое значение. Вот Катаев - да. Признаю свою ошибку, в таком использовании - фразеологизм.